# How to define a type parameter inside a type parameter in java generics

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

I have a message dto

```
class MyMessage<T>{
  T payload;
  String groupId;
}
```

I have an interface that has a simple implementation

```
interface Sender<T>{
    void sendMessage(T message);
}

class SenderService implements Sender<MyMessage>{
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(MyMessage message){...}
}
```

Now here MyMessage has a raw type and I want MyMessage to have a type paramter also which will define my payload dynamically. How to achieve it? I have tried the following.

```
class SenderService implements Sender<MyMessage>{
    @Override
    public <E> void sendMessage(MyMessage<E> message){...}
}
```

But it gives compilation error as the method is not overriden correctly. What I need to change in my abstract interface method to make it work?

Comment: If `SenderService` is a sender of `MyMessage<String>`, then wouldn't it only be able to send `MyMessage<String>`? Why is `sendMessage` to take a `MyMessage<E>` where `E` is any type?

Comment: SenderService can send any type of message. Not only String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Sender.sendMessage` isn't a generic method: you can't add a new type variable on an implementation of that method:

```
class SenderService implements Sender<MyMessage<String>>{
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(MyMessage<String> message){...}
}
```

If you want a `SenderService` that sends `MyMessage`s of any type type, make it implement a wildcarded type:

```
class SenderService implements Sender<MyMessage<?>>{
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(MyMessage<?> message){...}
}
```

If you want a `SenderService` that sends `MyMessage`s of a particular type, make `SenderService` generic:

```
class SenderService<E> implements Sender<MyMessage<E>>{
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(MyMessage<E> message){...}
}
```